# ExtJS 4.2 Scatter Chart series

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have two questions about [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27ml) Sencha Fiddle:

1.- Why when I click in some value in the legend it is not disapearing/hidding the serie from the chart.

2.- Why if I dont add **type: 'circle'** in the **markerConfig**, it adds random type markers but if I click some in the legend gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Ext.chart.Shape[markerConfig.type] is not a function

Am I missing something? Do I have something wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is a [reported bug](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?183975-Possible-Bug-Legend-toggle-function-doesn-t-work-without-shadow-on-Scatter-Chart) in the version used but is fixed in the later version. Please see the working code [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/286l).
2. This is also a bug. Please refer [here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?140932-How-to-add-more-than-3-SERIES-in-a-LINE-or-SCATTER-chart). This version requires to [explicitly specify the type of marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765750/how-to-add-more-than-3-series-in-a-line-or-scatter-chart). This is also resolved in the later version.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try